# How to align element at center bottom using flex box

Tags: html, css, button, flexbox

I am beginner and I am trying to align `span` element at parent element bottom side. For this I used below CSS, but why it's not working:

```css
.sidebarBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: -50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  background-color: beige;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebarBtn span {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="sidebarBtn">
  <span></span>
</button>
```

Comment: why are you using position absolute together with flex? Also, position absolute will only work if you have a position relative around it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a *column* flexbox and align it to bottom using `justify-content: flex-end` - see demo below:

```css
.sidebarBtn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column; /* ADDED */
  justify-content: flex-end; /* CHANGED */
  align-items: center; /* CHANGED */
  background-color: beige;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebarBtn span {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="sidebarBtn"><span></span></button>
```

But you'd think *why* your code wasn't working when it would work fine for a `div` but not a `button` element in this case - that is because `button` or `fieldset` elements are not designed to be a *flex container*. See how everything is normal when you keep the `flexbox` *inside* the button:

```css
.sidebarBtn {
  background-color: beige;
  outline: none;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
}

.sidebarBtn>span {
  border: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  height: 100%;
}

.sidebarBtn>span>span {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="sidebarBtn">
  <span>
    <span></span>
  </span>
</button>
```

Comment: I think he needs to align it **center** bottom

Comment: @Helenesh what do you mean by that?

Comment: Hi Kukuz why before and after selectors not working can you please help me

Comment: you can't update your question with fresh queries afterwards, I guess you should ask another question... I've rolled it back...

Comment: its not fresh query i just want to add after and before selectors

Comment: tried it out... `before` and `after` is working fine, where do you want it to be *positioned*?

Comment: please note that when you use `position: absolute` you *should* be using `position: relative` to the element with respect to which you want to *position* it...

Answer (score 0):

I think `button` cannot be flex containers, they can only be flex elements.

This code should work but I'm not sure if that's the best way to do it.
It works on Chrome, you might have to try on different browsers.

```css
.sidebarBtn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 500px;
  border: none;
  background-color: beige;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.sidebarBtnContent {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  justify-content: center;
}

.sidebarBtnContent span {
  width: 35px;
  height: 3px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<button class="sidebarBtn">
  <span class="sidebarBtnContent">
    <span></span>
  </span>
</button>
```